# How do I match the number of days in a month to a list level and carry out arithmetic in R

Tags: r, list

I need to multiply the data in each level of a list (each of which correspond to a month) by the number of days in that month.

My list looks like this:

```
tmintest=array(0.11:100.4, c(1,256,512))
l <- lapply(1:12, function(i) {
#create the list
Variable <- list(varName = c("tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin","tmin"),level = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
Data = tmintest
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(-40.37,64.37,length.out=420), y = seq(25.37,72.37,length.out=189))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="days"), end=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by="days"))
Delta <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=Data, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
})
```

I think I need to define the months and the number of days per month:

```
  mth <- c(1:12)
```

#Number of days by month

```
  ndays <- c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)
```

Then make a dataframe with this information

```
mthdays<- as.data.frame(cbind(mth, ndays))
```

Then I need to match the number in each level of the list (for example January is `l[[1]]`)to my `ndays` (via the `mth`) and multiply the `Data` in that level (`l[[1]][["Data"]]`) by `ndays`. I think using `which` might be useful (matching the number at each level of my list to the `mth` in my dataframe, but I'm unsure as to the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `for` loop.  As the `length` of `list` is 12 and is in the same order as the `ndays`, just loop over the sequence of `l`, extract the `list` element with position index, get the inner named list element 'Data' (using `$`) and multiply with the corresponding 'ndays' element

```
for(i in seq_along(l)) l[[i]]$Data <- l[[i]]$Data * ndays[i]
```